# wget js redirection

Tags: javascript, bash, wget

When I was using wget I came to the page witch using JS redirections. Something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
var s = "i_08/0101/index.php3";
location.href=""+s;
</script>
```

Could wget follow this redirection or is there any other method to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the [DHTMLGET](http://code.google.com/p/dhtmlget/) tool that was built for [FAE](http://faeserv.dres.uiuc.edu/). The goal of this project is to provide basic inline js and onload events on top of a modified wget:

> The dhtmlget utility is to create local copies of websites similar to WGET utility in unix. It supports http, https protocols, as well as retrieval through http proxies.The main difference of DHTMLGET and WGET is the dhtmlget ExecuteS onload and inline javascript. It was developed for use in the Illinois Functional Accessibility Evaluator to analyze websites that use javascrpt to generate content for accessibility features.

A simple Google search can lead you to an interesting page about [wget js feature request](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FeatureSpecifications/JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

`wget` is used for downloading the remote location as-is and does not act as a web browser, which parses the contained JavaScript.

Note that `wget` *does* follow header redirects (such as 301, for example).

I tried using `lynx -source` but sadly, this will result in a non-parsed web page as well. An **alternative solution** to this problem would be to write a script that downloads the page, then parses it and downloads possible references automatically, but I'll leave that up to you.